# htaccess redirect only for one domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have several domains pointing to the same webspace (www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com, www.domain3.com, etc.). Only when one domain is used, e.g. www.domain1.com, I want to redirect users from different short link, e.g. www.domain1.com/link or www.domain1.com/link2, to another URL.

I have put together the following. The RewriteCond is probably ok but the RewriteRules doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/test$ http://www.domain1.com/xyz.php [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/test2$ http://www.domain1.com/abc.php [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/test3$ http://www.domain1.com/abc/test10.php [L,R=301]
```

Do you have any tip how the correct RewriteRules should look like?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps you get going in the right direction...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/test/)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/xyz.php [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/test2/)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/abc.php [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/test3/)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/abc/test10.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks complicated ... So I need to add three lines for each redirect URL. I have 30+ redirect URLs in my htaccess file. Is it possible to write just one RewriteCond, below it in one line each redirect and the RewriteCond applies to all Redirects like: 1st line: RewriteRule ..., 2nd line: Redirect ..., 3rd line: Redirect ..., etc.?

Comment: Actually if the .htaccess file only applies to one domain (e.g. `domain1.com`) then you should be able to eliminate the lines that say `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]`... Other than that though I'm not sure there's much else you can do using .htaccess. Using PHP however, you could hypothetically put a file named `index.php` in each of the dirs you listed, and inside each of the index files put something like:
`<?php header('Location: http://www.domain1.com/xyz.php');`